# jquery autocomplete with mockjax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete, mockjax

I am new to mackjax, pls tell me how to use the given below code for data coming from a url instead of local data i.e. countries array. The code is working fine for local array in the file i.e. `countries{}` but how to make it work for the data coming from a url

```
var countries= {
                "AZ": "Azerbaijan",
                "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina",

            }

var countriesArray = $.map(countries, function (value, key) { return { value: value, data: key }; });

// Setup jQuery ajax mock:
$.mockjax({
    url: '*',
    responseTime: 2000,
    response: function (settings) {
        var query = settings.data.query,
            queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase(),
            re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi'),
            suggestions = $.grep(countriesArray, function (country) {
                 // return country.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryLowerCase) === 0;
                return re.test(country.value);
            }),
            response = {
                query: query,
                suggestions: suggestions
            };

        this.responseText = JSON.stringify(response);
    }
});

// Initialize ajax autocomplete:
$('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
    // serviceUrl: '/autosuggest/service/url',
    lookup: countriesArray,
    lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
        var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
        return re.test(suggestion.value);
    },
    onSelect: function(suggestion) {
        $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    },
    onHint: function (hint) {
        $('#autocomplete-ajax-x').val(hint);
    },
    onInvalidateSelection: function() {
        $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: none');
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve using all that code? Why have you written such code if it does not solve your problem?

Comment: code is working perfectly for the array available in the the same file i.e in this case var country{} but i my case the array is coming from a url ? thats the problem

Comment: Why is that a problem? What does that URL return for you? Couldn't you parse whatever comes back and use that instead of the array?

Comment: Why are you using Mockjax here? Are you trying to test your autocomplete code?

Comment: @jakerella sorry to dissapoint you but its in the theme for autocomplete and removing the mockjax code stops the functioning of autocomplete.
Pls help......

Comment: @KrishnaSingh I'm not sure what you mean by "its in the theme"... Mockjax is not in the jQuery UI autocomplete widget source code. It looks like you are using it, but I'm not sure why. Mockjax is a tool for mocking out API endpoints in order to test front end code separate from back end code. That said, I still don't know what your issue is... what error are you seeing, or what is not happening _exactly_?

Comment: "its in the theme" means the admin template i am using for my project has this custom script for autocomplete and it works perfectly with locally defined array as defined above "var countries" but i need to know how i can get a array from a url i.e. i am getting my array from the database.